# Как определенное количество элементов распределить в несколько массивов?

Tags: php, массивы

Посоветуйте пожалуйста как решить, не могу выполнить последнее задание ТЗ.

Вот условие:

> Дано 10 овец, нужно распределить рандомно в 4 загона с добавлением
>   номера (Овца1, Овца2 и тд). Массивы не должны быть пустыми и должны
>   быть заполненными хотя бы одним элементом.

Comment: А что именно не получается-то? (только не надо писать, что всё)

Comment: Так если у Вас овцы одинаковы, так берите всех подряд и пихайте  по 4 в 3 первых загона и в последний 2. Попутно каждой клейте метки с номером. Ну или если нужно поровну то тогда будет по 3 целых овцы и по 3/4 овцы в каждом загоне.  Если не подходит вариант - напишите что уже у Вас получилось накодить. Тогда будет проще Вам помочь.

Comment: `array_chunk()`

Comment: @V.March, пока только как одномерный массив с добавлением номеров к овцам. А вот с рандомным распределением на 4 массива я не знаю как сделать. Как я понял из условия должно быть минимум одна овца в каждом из загонов и общее количество в загонах не должно превышать изначально кол-во. Вот мой код: `$sheepNames = [ ];
for($i = 1; $i<=10; $i++){
    $sheepNames[$i]= 'Овца' . $i;
}
print_r($sheepNames);

foreach($sheepNames as $key => $name){
    $sheeps []= new Sheep($name);
}
print_r($sheeps);`

Comment: @u_mulder, извините, но ваш вариант мне не подходит так как мне не многомерный массив нужен, да и размер может быть от 1 до 7 элементов, а в предложенной функции нужно указывать размер вложенного массива

Comment: 1) В условии задачи не видно что все 4 массива должны быть непустыми.  Добавьте это условие в вопрос. 2) Как Вы представляете одномерный массив поделенный на 4 части?

Comment: У Вас варианты либо писать строчные значения "Овца1" и т.д.  и дописывать новую овцу а каждую из 4-х ячеек строчного одномерного массива. Либо сделать 4 одномерных массива.

Comment: Так же вам нужен генератор случайних чисел который либо будет генерить  цифры от 0 до 3 (если применять его к ячейкам двумерного массива, либо одномерным массивам)  либо будет генерить от 1 до 10 если применять к овцам. Смотря на что Вы первично направите цикл который этих овец будет раскидывать по загонам.

Comment: @V.March, спасибо за советы, сейчас попробую

Answer (score 0):

Привет ))) Увидел тут задачку. Во время решения изрядно похохотал сам с себя)))
Решение может показаться странным, но оно работает )
Количество овец в массиве и количество загонов можно устанавливать любое по желанию)))
С наступившим новым годом.

```
$input = array("Овца1", "Овца2", "Овца3", "Овца4", "Овца5", "Овца6", "Овца7", "Овца8", "Овца9", "Овца10");

$Zagon = 4;
$count = count($input);
if ($Zagon > $count){
    echo 'Загонов больше, чем овец. Пусть размножаются пока';
} else {
    for ($i = 1; $i < $Zagon; $i++) {
        $c = count($input);
        $rnum = count($input) - $Zagon + $i; // Получаем максимально число диапазона для получения рандомного числа. (Количество овец минус количество загонов и +$i, так как в загоне должен быть хотябы одна овца.
        $RundomInt1 = rand(1, $rnum); // Получаем рандомное число от 1 до $RundomInt1
        $randindex123 = array_rand($input, $RundomInt1); // Рандомно выбираем из главного массива равндомное количество овец, которое получили. Если просто rand_array, то выбрать он может больше овец, чем должно было остаться для других загонов.
        $checkarr = is_array($randindex123) ? '1' : '2';  // Проверяем, является ли массивом $randindex123, потмоу что, если единица, то array_flip выдаст ошибку.
        if ($checkarr == "2") { // Если $randindex123 не массив, то делаем из него массив.
            $arr = array();
            $arr[0] = $randindex123;
            $randindex123 = $arr;
        }
        $revers = array_flip($randindex123);  // Меняем местами ключи и значения для сравнения.
        $zagon1 = array_intersect_key($input, $revers);  // берём из массива овец по полученным ключам
        foreach ($zagon1 as $key) {
            $input1 = array_diff_key($input, $revers); // Из основного массива делаем массив с не выбранными овцами в первый загон.
        }
        $input = array_values($input1); // Сбрасываем ключи для красоты
        $zagon1 = array_values($zagon1); // Сбрасываем ключи для красоты
        echo 'Загон ' . $i . ':';
        print_r($zagon1);
        echo '<br>';
    }
    echo 'Загон ' . $Zagon . ':';
    print_r($input);
    echo '<br>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$arr = range(1, 10);//создам массив

shuffle($arr);//перемешаю
print_r($arr);

foreach($arr as &$v)
    {
        $v = 'овца'.$v;//добавлю слово
    }
unset($v);
print_r($arr);

$arr = array_chunk($arr, 3);//двумерный массив

shuffle($arr);//перемешаю или тут уже лишнее?
print_r($arr);

[$arr1,$arr2,$arr3,$arr4] = $arr;//из 1 двумерного 4 одномерных массива

print_r($arr1);
print_r($arr2);
print_r($arr3);
print_r($arr4);
```